# Python _getitem_ and _getitem_column(key) error when load data from excel

Tags: pandas, error-handling

I have a dataframe, with 20 different sheets. It ran normally for the first 16 sheets, but on the 17th sheet it raised an error. Here is my code:

```
A=A.sort_values(by=['timing','id'])
```

The error was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-24-11bf4f35bb1b>", line 1, in <module>
    SessionNumber(5)

  File "filepath", line 160
    DepthBuyA=DepthBuyA.sort_values(by=['timing','id'])

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4411, in sort_values
    stacklevel=stacklevel)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1382, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: 'id'
```

So I thought, there must be some problem with the column 'id' on that particular sheet, because other sheets also had 'id' and none of which raised an error like that. So I tried:

```
print(A['id'])
```

And it successfully printed the column 'id' for sheet 17, however, right after printing it, it raised this error:

```
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2688, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2695, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2489, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4115, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'id'
```

So after that I tried the code by putting it directly into the console, and now there is no error.

```
A=A.sort_values(by=['timing','id'])
```

So what is the problem and what can I do to fix?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Used column index instead of name, it is fine now